# Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I was trying to update my Android Studio 2.2.3 to version 3 but when i did, below error blocked the build process :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3.
>
> > Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3.
> >     Required by:
> >         project :app
> >
> > > Could not resolve com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3.
> > >
> > > > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/multidex/1.0.3/multidex-1.0.3.pom
> > > >
> > > > > Already seen doctype.

**build.gradle(Module: app) :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
    google()
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "My.App.Id"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 111
        versionName "1.1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:+'
    compile files('libs/devicedriverslib.jar')
    compile files('libs/allutils.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

**build.gradle(Project: MyProjectName)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

}
```

**Installed Build Tools :**
[image]

**gradle-wrapper.properties :**

```
#Tue Oct 31 12:15:03 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Comment: What is the need of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'` inside the app gradle file?

Comment: it is neccessary as it is mentioned in the [samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are behind a firewall or even if you are in a forbidden country, you have to bypass the restrictions via a VPN tool or add the correct exceptions in the firewall. (free proxies like Psyphon and weak stuff won't work! you might wanna consider buying a good VPN!)

the problem is about correct internet connection, so double check your network and internet connection and any limitations related.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem since i had set Global Gradle settings to Offline work

1. Click **File > Settings** (on macOS, **Android Studio > Preferences**) to open the **Settings** dialog.
2. In the left pane, expand **Build, Execution, Deployment** and then click **Gradle**.
3. Under Global Gradle settings, uncheck the **Offline work** checkbox.
4. Click **Apply** or **OK** for your changes to take effect.
5. Rebuild Gradle

Source: [Configure Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config)